# convert boost beast http request to a string and write to ostringstream

Tags: boost, boost-beast, ostringstream

I am trying to make a http call using boost beast and want to write it before writing to socket; i tried to use ostringstream to get the value of request to get it in printed log and getting the below error message:

```
string verb = "POST";
using http::field;
http::request<http::string_body> request;
request.method_string(verb);
request.target(server_endpoint);
request.version(11);
request.set(field::host, hostname);
request.set(field::accept, "*/*");
request.set(field::authorization, authorization_token);
request.set(field::user_agent, client_name);
request.set(field::content_length, req_str.length());
request.set(field::content_type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.set(field::connection, field::close);
request.body() = req_str;
request.prepare_payload();
fast_ostringstream oss;
oss <<"Request message" << request;
PBLOG_INFO(oss.str());
oss.clear();



HttpTracRequestHandler.cpp:78:26: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('framework::string_::fast_ostringstream' and
      'http::request<http::string_body>' (aka 'boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::basic_string_body<char,
      std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> > >'))
        oss <<"Request message" << request;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~
/BARXPBViewstore/GIT_Workspace/barx_rel/mq8_barx/barx-server/appl/include/FoxException/GenericException.h:133:19: note: candidate function
      [with TData = boost::beast::http::message<true, boost::beast::http::basic_string_body<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      std::allocator<char> >, boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> > >] not viable: no known conversion from
      'framework::string_::fast_ostringstream' to 'GenericException &' for 1st argument
GenericException& operator<<(GenericException &e, const TData& data)
                  ^
/BARXPBViewstore/GIT_Workspace/boost/boost_1_70_0/boost/beast/http/impl/write.hpp:921:1: note: candidate function [with isRequest = true,
      Body = boost::beast::http::basic_string_body<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, Fields =
      boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >] not viable: no known conversion from 'framework::string_::fast_ostringstream'
      to 'std::ostream &' (aka 'basic_ostream<char> &') for 1st argument
operator<<(std::ostream& os,
^
/BARXPBViewstore/GIT_Workspace/boost/boost_1_70_0/boost/beast/http/write.hpp:721:1: note: candidate function [with isRequest = true, Fields
      = boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >] not viable: no known conversion from
      'framework::string_::fast_ostringstream' to 'std::ostream &' (aka 'basic_ostream<char> &') for 1st argument
operator<<(std::ostream& os,
^
/BARXPBViewstore/GIT_Workspace/boost/boost_1_70_0/boost/beast/http/impl/write.hpp:901:1: note: candidate function [with Fields =
      boost::beast::http::basic_fields<std::allocator<char> >] not viable: no known conversion from 'framework::string_::fast_ostringstream'
      to 'std::ostream &' (aka 'basic_ostream<char> &') for 1st argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks normal. In fact it works with standard string streams:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cc10bf9c21f069d)**

```
#include <boost/beast/http.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

namespace http = boost::beast::http;

#define PBLOG_INFO(a) do { std::clog << (a) << std::endl; } while(0);

int main() {
    std::string verb = "POST", req_str = "payload";
    using http::field;
    http::request<http::string_body> request;
    request.method_string(verb);
    request.target("server_endpoint");
    request.version(11);
    request.set(field::host, "hostname");
    request.set(field::accept, "*/*");
    request.set(field::authorization, "authorization_token");
    request.set(field::user_agent, "client_name");
    request.set(field::content_length, req_str.length());
    request.set(field::content_type, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.set(field::connection, field::close);
    request.body() = req_str;
    request.prepare_payload();

    {
        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss <<"Request message " << request;
        PBLOG_INFO(oss.str());
        oss.clear();
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Request message POST server_endpoint HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname
Accept: */*
Authorization: authorization_token
User-Agent: client_name
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 7
payload
```

### What Is The Problem?

The problem appears to be that Beast's streaming operators overloads do not apply to whatever type `fast_ostringstream` is. That's by design:

```
  no known conversion from 'framework::string_::fast_ostringstream'
  to 'std::ostream &' (aka 'basic_ostream<char> &')
```

The authors `fast_ostringstream` apparently cheated in the sense that it might be fast, but it definitely isn't an `ostream&` :).

I tried to get a similar error by creating my own cheating stream:

```
struct my_cheat_stream {
    using Device = boost::iostreams::back_insert_device<std::string>;
    using Stream = boost::iostreams::stream<Device>;

    std::string buf;
    Stream _impl { buf };

    template <typename T> my_cheat_stream& operator<<(T&& rhs) {
        _impl << std::forward<T>(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    std::string&&    str()&& { _impl.flush(); return std::move(buf); }
    std::string_view str()&  { _impl.flush(); return buf; }

    void clear() {
        buf.clear();
        _impl.clear(std::ios::failbit|std::ios::badbit);
    }
};
```

However, [it simply compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4051481ce7b14d5), because, obviously, `operator<< <T>()` just applies. Perhaps you can fix your `fast_ostringstream` accordingly, or use something else.

### Dirty Workaround:

You could use the above counter-example as leverage:

```
template <typename Stream> struct wrap_non_std_stream {
    Stream& _wrapped;
    explicit wrap_non_std_stream(Stream& ref) : _wrapped(ref) {}

    template <typename T> auto& operator<<(T const& rhs) {
        _wrapped << rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    auto& operator<<(std::ostream&(*manip)(std::ostream&)) {
        _wrapped << manip;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Now you should be able to

```
    fast_ostringstream oss;
    wrap_non_std_stream woss{oss};
    woss << "Request message " << request;
```

If the underlying stream does, it will also support manipulators:

```
    woss << std::endl << std::fixed << std::boolalpha << std::flush;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sehe. I have used ostringstream oss; to print in the logs and we are able to hit destiantion url and able to parse the response using boost beast.